# POST xml WITHOUT using CURL

Tags: php, xml, post

I need to POST xml data without CuRL.

there are a LOT of snippets, but nothing seems to work. 
The latest attempt:

```
function salesOrder($xml, $url)
{

  $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/xml\r\n",
      'content' => $xml,
      'timeout' => 5,
    ),
  ));
  $ret = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  return false !== $ret;
}
```

returns nothing, blank page.

I have tried http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

The problem is I dont really understand it and i can not seem to find a good tutorial that covers this problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't say "it doesnt work", because it's not descriptive. Say what you expect to happen, and what actually happens, and be very specific. Anyway, turn up error reporting and check your error log. You need to learn basic debugging techniques.

Comment: What's wrong with cURL? That's a little like saying "I need to cut a tree down without any sharp objects."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to achieve that

```
$xml = "<xml><name>hello</name></xml>" ;
$opts = array (
        'http' => array (
                'method' => "POST",
                'content' => $xml,
                'timeout' => 5,
                'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
        ) 
);

$context = stream_context_create ( $opts );
$fp = fopen ( 'http://example.com/b.php', 'r', false, $context );
fpassthru ( $fp );
fclose ( $fp );
```

**http://example.com/b.php**

```
file_put_contents("php://output", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: can you explain what i am doing with file_put_contents?

Comment: You are reading the incoming data with `file_get_contents("php://input")` then writing it back with `file_put_contents("php://output"` .. if you run this on your browsers you would see the full xml document that was sent